# Can I overwrite an Eclipse Developer Build over a stable Eclipse installation?

Tags: eclipse, installation

I already have an existing Eclipse environment (eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-win32-x86_64.zip), with plug-ins already installed / set-up.

I want to try out the Developer Build without re-configuring my workspace and reinstalling plug-ins. Can I just download the Developer Build (eclipse-standard-luna-RC3-win32-x86_64.zip) and overwrite it over my stable Eclipse folder / installation?

Comment: As stated in the answer you should **never** just overwrite stuff in the Eclipse installation as this will not update Eclipse's database of installed plugins. You can install Luna in a new location.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend you to try to override your eclipse installation. The result might be worse than reinstalling a few plugins. When you just copy and paste the installation, you will end with two versions of all your plugins, since they are renamed with a new version number. There is a reason, why it is strongly recomemnded to not copy plugins in your *plugins* folder.

Apart of that, your old installed plugins are not guaranteed to work with the new platform, which might cause your whole installation to crash or not even start.

Your workspace preferences will still work in your new IDE, when you load your workspace. Those preferences are saved in your workspace. So all templates and settings willl still work.

I'd recommend you to download the Eclipse version you want and install all features you need.

What you might try is *Help -> Install new Software* and then point to a Kepler updatesite and try to update your eclipse. But you'd have to update all plugins that are not on the Kepler updatesite, too. And when you do that, you might end spending even more time, since the updatesites are regularly way slower than downloading a new Eclipse version.